# How to get an id parameter from json rpc with jsonprc4j

Tags: spring-boot, json-rpc, jsonrpc4j

I need the id parameter of json-rpc. Is there a way to get this parameter from the jsonrpc4j library?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdxeq.png)
Values of parameters are parsed well into objects using @JsonRpcParam.

but
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQ5GE.png)
This parameter is not parsed

Thank you